# Grouping sql rows by weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

```
DATE        Val
01-01-2020  1
01-02-2020  3
01-05-2020  2
01-07-2020  8
01-13-2020  3
...
```

I want to summarize these values by the *following* Sunday. For example, in the above example:

1-05-2020, 1-12-2020, and 1-19-2020 are Sundays, so I want to summarize these by those dates.

The final result should be something like

```
DATE       SUM
1-05-2020  6    //(01-01-2020 + 01-02-2020 + 01-05-2020)
1-12-2020  8
1-19-2020  3
```

I wasn't certain if the best place to start would be to create a temp calendar table, and then try to join backwards based on that? Or if there was an easier way involving DATEDIFF. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You said you want to aggreate by sunday but 1-13-2020 is not a sunday Remh

Comment: @zip apologies you're correct, it should sum up on 1-19-2020 in that case; edited to reflect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses DATEADD & DATEPART to calculate the closest Sunday.

With a correction for a different setting of `@@datefirst`.
*(Since the datepart weekday values are different depending on the DATEFIRST setting)*

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table #TestTable
> (
>   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   [Date] date,
>   Val int
> );
>
> insert into #TestTable
>  ([Date], Val)
>  VALUES
>   ('2020-01-01', 1)
> , ('2020-01-02', 3)
> , ('2020-01-05', 2)
> , ('2020-01-07', 8)
> , ('2020-01-13', 3)
> ;
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   SELECT [Date], Val
>   , DATEADD(day, 
>      ((7-(@@datefirst+datepart(weekday, [Date])-1)%7)%7),
>      [Date]) AS Sunday
>   FROM #TestTable
> )
> SELECT 
> Sunday AS [Date],
> SUM(Val) AS [Sum]
> FROM CTE_DATA
> GROUP BY Sunday
> ORDER BY Sunday;
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | Sum
> :--------- | --:
> 2020-01-05 |   6
> 2020-01-12 |   8
> 2020-01-19 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10f5daf183163c13ac34b8fdc0f13d57)*

**Extra:**

Apparently the trick of adding the difference of weeks from day 0 to day 6 also works independently from the DATEFIRST setting.
So this query will return the same result for the sample data.

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS
(
  SELECT [Date], Val
  , CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(day, -1, [Date])), 6) AS DATE) AS Sunday
  FROM #TestTable
)
SELECT
Sunday AS [Date],
SUM(Val) AS [Sum]
FROM CTE_DATA
GROUP BY Sunday
ORDER BY Sunday;
```

The subtraction of 1 day makes sure that if the date is already a Sunday that it isn't calculated to the next Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:
nb:1-13-2020  wont show cuz its not a sunday

```
with cte as
(        
select cast('01-01-2020'as Date) as Date,  1 as Val
union select '01-02-2020' , 3
union select '01-05-2020' , 2
union select '01-07-2020' , 8
)

select Date, max(dateadd(dd,number,Date)), sum(distinct Val) as SUM
from master..spt_values a inner join cte on Date <= dateadd(dd,number,Date) 
where type = 'p'
and year(dateadd(dd,number,Date))=year(Date)
and DATEPART(dw,dateadd(dd,number,Date)) = 7 
group by Date
```

Output:

```
Date    (No column name)    SUM
2020-01-01  2020-12-26       1
2020-01-02  2020-12-26       3
2020-01-05  2020-12-26       2
2020-01-07  2020-12-26       8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Putting your values into a temporary table and viewing the results on that table:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE
(
    mDATE DATE,
    Val INT,
    Sunday DATE
)

INSERT INTO @dates (mDATE,Val) VALUES
('01-01-2020',1),('01-02-2020',3),('01-05-2020',2),('01-07-2020',8),('01-13-2020',3)

UPDATE @dates
SET Sunday = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, mDATE), 6)

SELECT Sunday,SUM(Val) AS Val FROM @dates
GROUP BY Sunday
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sunday      Val
2020-01-05  4
2020-01-12  10
2020-01-19  3
```